# Alternative for <BR> using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using `br` tag to create a line break for my web page `faq`. 
Though the results are accurate, is there any alternative for using `linebreak` 
 
via css to create responsive based web page. 
By googling I found the `pseudo` element. But I didnt get a proper image of it.

```css
.faqfirstsec {
  margin: 0 0 0 70px;
  background: lightgrey;
  height: 100%;
}

font.faqtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

font.faqques {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="faqfirstsec">
  <font class="faqtitle" weight="bold">TITLE</font><br><br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <font class="faqques">QUESTION 1</font><br><br>
  <font class="faqans">ANSWER 1<br> ANSWER 1。</font><br><br><br><br><br>
  <font class="faqques">QUESTION 2</font><br> ANSWER 2<br><br><br><br>
  <font class="faqques">QUESTION 3</font><br> ANSWER 3<br><br>
</div>
```

I want to create some spaces among question 1 , 2 and so on. 
I have used `font class` tag , but cannot use `Margin` . 
Should I go for `DIV` instead of `FONT` ?

Comment: `font` is deprecated, use `div` with a margin

Comment: `font` tag is deprecated. Also, if you are using so many `br` tags then you are surely doing something wrong. You need to learn CSS positioning.

Comment: @LGSon So giving `DIV` for each and every `question ` and `answer` line and setting a `margin ` ?

Comment: @LGSon Your code looks clean and much organized using `DIV` . Any chance I can mark your comment as Answer?

Comment: Can't accept comments as answers. Await the given answerer, they might use mine (asked them too), and the duplicate link might be a good reference, so I'm considering close it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the Help. Ok I will Close it.

Comment: I have added a new part to my answer to show how to do this in your sample :)

Comment: I have added a new part to my answer to show how to do this in your sample :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.faqfirstsec {
 margin: 0 0 0 70px;
 background: lightgrey;
  height : 100%;           /* this doesn't do much unless parent has a height */
}

.faqtitle {
 font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.faqques {
 color: red;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.faqans {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="faqfirstsec">
  <div class="faqtitle">TITLE</div>

  <div class ="faqques">QUESTION 1</div>
  <div class="faqans">ANSWER 1<br>ANSWER 1</div>
  
  <div class ="faqques">QUESTION 2</div>
  <div class="faqans">ANSWER 2<br>ANSWER 2</div>
  
  <div class ="faqques">QUESTION 3</div>
  <div class="faqans">ANSWER 3<br>ANSWER 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your desired text (contains `<br/>`) in an element with `white-space: pre` all `\n`s will render as `<br/>`.

Also you can use `<pre></pre>` tag which wrapped your text.

**But about** `HTML`, You can do it like this:

```
 <span>hello</span><span data-x>BR!</span>
```

And its css (excuse me for no snippet or fiddle, I'm typing with my mobile phone and I haven't access to the code tools of `stackoverflow`'s editor):

```
[data-x]:before{
    content: "\A";
    white-space: pre;
 }
```

---

**Added part**

Now, for your case, only try this:

```
.faqans:before{
    content:"\A\A\A";/*per be, one \A*/
    white-space:pre;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
margin-bottom: 100px;
display: block;
```

for the font tag.

font tag is an inline element and now it is deprecated. Instead of font tag use Div or span.

Comment: @LGSon, Both are the same answers. Why did you added downvote to my answer.

Comment: Because you suggest how to use `font` (displayed as block though). `font` is deprecated and shouldn't be used, so an answer with it, is a bad answer.

Comment: I was mentioned that font tag was deprecated.

Comment: You still refer the given CSS for the font tag. Some users will just try the provided CSS, and as that (still) might work they might keep it and then it suddenly will not, so I suggest you rephrase the answer